# libGDX, Box2D, collision and forbid jump in the air

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx, collision

I'm programming a ball game and I want the ball can't jump twice, or jump without having contact with the floor.

I'm using the methods `beginContact()` and `endContact()` from `ContactListener` for detect when the ball **is touching** the floor. I implemented a state (`FLYING` or `LANDED`) and I set the ball state to `LANDED` in the `beginContact()` method, and reset it to `FLYING` in the `endContact()` method. I check this state before apply the jump force.

The problem is that the `jump()` method is called in the main render loop and box2D sometimes spends two loop iterations before call `endContact()` method. So the `jump()` method is called twice before that box2D simulates that the contact with the floor has ended.

Part of the code of `ContactListener` (This isn't the `ContactListener` of libGDX, but the methods `beginContact()` and `endContact()` call these methods directly, passing the object which it was collide):

```
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact, Object objetB) {
    if(objetB instanceof Floor){
        System.out.println("Begin");
        ball.floorBeginContact(contact);
    }
}

@Override
public void endContact(Contact contact, Object objetB) {
    if(objetB instanceof Floor){
        System.out.println("End");
        ball.floorEndContact(contact);
    }       
}
```

Part of the code of the ball `Actor`:

```
public void floorBeginContact(Contact contact){
    state = State.LANDED;
}

public void floorEndContact(Contact contact){
    state = State.FLYING;
}

private void jump(){
    if(state == State.LANDED){
        body.applyForceToCenter(0f, 30f);
        System.out.println(i++ + " - Jump!");
    }
}

public void act(float delta){
    ...

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)){
        jump();
    }
}
```

And the console output is some like this:

```
Begin
0 - Jump!
1 - Jump!
End
Begin
2 - Jump!
End
```

I don't know why this happens and neither if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: How about having a timeout of say, 0.2 seconds or something, before allowing another jump.

Comment: Solution from ifroce2d: https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumpability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void floorBeginContact(Contact contact){
state = State.LANDED;
 canApplyForce = true;
}

public void floorEndContact(Contact contact){
state = State.FLYING;
}

boolean canApplyForce = true;

private void jump(){
if(state == State.LANDED){
    if(canApplyForce)
    body.applyForceToCenter(0f, 30f);
   canApplyForce = false;
    System.out.println(i++ + " - Jump!");
}
}

public void act(float delta){
...

if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)){
    jump();
 }
   }
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: This has the drawback that if the jump attempt does not separate the player from the ground (eg. if something heavy is on top of them), then canApplyForce will not be reset to true.

Comment: Thats exactly what he want....jump cannot be initiated. He want to jump only once when the ball touches the ground. 
Next jump can only be made when he leaves the ground and again touches it.

Comment: Right. And if there is something heavy on top, he will never leave the ground and touch it again, so canApplyForce will not be reset to true, and he will not be able to jump any more after that. That's probably not what he wants.

Comment: I appreciate your concern sir and you are right but all these things depends on the developer which he wants. In this question he wants to have callback once when it touches the ground and next callback can only be recieved when he again touches the ground.
And if there is something heavy on the object he will not recieve any callback because he had not left the ground to recieve another callback but all these depends on the dynamics he want and he had to work it out accordingly.